# How to serve static files from Apache Server (not from Tomcat)

Tags: apache, tomcat, webserver

I am running my Web application project using Tomcat alone. Now I would like to improve my site performance using Apache altogether with Tomcat. And static contents like css, images, js have to be served from Apache not form Tomcat.
I have heard like Apache httpd and Ant build files has to modified to meet out my requirement.

Can anyone suggest what should be done?

Thanks in advance!!!